# Ubuntu 16.04LTS Locking down gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, lock

I have setup Ubuntu 16.04LTS with classic gnome instead of unity using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback
```

I would like to be able to set and fix the background, launchers, menu items and panel items. I would like to prevent any standard users from changing these settings without admin access. I have looked at lockdown editor pessulus which seems ideal however its not available for 16.04 or 14.04.

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.